# How to include a dynamically generated SVG to a Vaadin UI?

Tags: jakarta-ee, svg, vaadin

I'd like to know if it is possible in Vaadin 7.0.5 to include SVG graphics in a vaadin UI, and this without any add-ons.

I'm currently using this code

```
StreamResource ressourceSVG = new StreamResource(source, "graphe.svg");

Embedded embedded = new Embedded("SVG", ressourceSVG);
embedded.setType(Embedded.TYPE_OBJECT);
embedded.setMimeType("images/svg+xml");

verticalLayout.addComponent(embedded);
setContent(verticalLayout);
```

And with this, just nothing happens... Only the appearance of the "SVG" text in the browser.

The only [topic](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/230295) i found on this subject dated from 3 years ago and didn't find a clue in the book.

In the API only interfaces exists : [elemental.svg](https://vaadin.com/api/elemental/svg/package-summary.html) but it's not really helping...

If you guys have any clue... would be great

Comment: what happens? what does not happen?

Comment: @nexus The only thing that happens is the appearance of the SVG text.
In the generated HTML i just have the "SVG" text generated by this element nothing else.

Comment: what happens if you use TYPE_IMAGE or TYPE_BROWSER instead of TYPE_OBJECT?

Comment: Didn't tryied TYPE_BROWSER yet, but TYPE_IMAGE is deprecated, i tried  the vaadin Class Image wich is the replacement of TYPE_IMAGE but it didn't work.
Since TYPE_BROWSER is also deprecated i'll try with the ,ew BrowserFrame Class which should be the same

Comment: The browserFrame Class makes it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, seems the answer is that for a SVG to be displayed in Vaadin 7 one should use the BrowserFrame to display the SVG resource.

Using something like below where sourceSVG is a streamSource containing the SVG data.

```
StreamResource ressourceSVG = new StreamResource(sourceSVG, "graphe.svg");

BrowserFrame embedded = new BrowserFrame("SVG", ressourceSVG);

verticalLayout.addComponent(component);
verticalLayout.addComponent(embedded);
setContent(verticalLayout);
```

Had to reload the frame after loading the  webpage but it finally worked

Answer (score 2):

Actually, at least in version `7.1.7`, you can use `Embedded` with SVGs directly. There is even an example in the [Book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.embedded.html), although it deals with a `ThemeResource`:

```
// A resource reference to some object
Resource res = new ThemeResource("img/reindeer.svg");

// Display the object
Embedded object = new Embedded("My SVG", res);
object.setMimeType("image/svg+xml"); // Unnecessary
layout.addComponent(object);
```

However, `StreamResource`s also work fine, at least with the following snippet:

```
Embedded image = new Embedded();
image.setMimeType("image/svg+xml"); //also unnecessary here :p
layout.addComponent(image);
StreamSource source = //define your source
image.setSource(new StreamResource(source, "image.svg"));
```

(note that if you need to regenerate your image, you have to provide a fresh, unique `filename` value for the `StreamResource`)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i'll try to remember it when i'll update my vaadin app